# How to enforce gradle plugins applying order?

Tags: gradle

In our company we wrote custom gradle plugin which is doing some stuff when application plugin is present. But when application plugin is included in build.gradle after our plugin, our plugin doesn't discover application plugin and actions are not executed.

Is there any way in gradle to enforce plugin applying order? Or any other solution?

Small excerpt from our plugin:

```
void apply(Project project) {
        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin(ApplicationPlugin) {
             //some stuff, doesn't work if "application" appears after this plugin
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to [this thread on the Gradle forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/adding-stuff-to-tasks-when-plugin-order-is-unknown/9236/4), `withType(Class)` and `withId(String)` are lazily evaluated and only applied when the referenced plugin is applied.

```
void apply(Project project) {
    project.plugins.withType(ApplicationPlugin) {
        //some stuff, doesn't work if "application" appears after this plugin
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I know after some investigating, only solution is preserving order of applied plugins.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use plugin dependencies. Your custom gradle plugin should be dependent on ApplicationPlugin.

See following code from GroovyPlugin which is dependent on JavaPlugin.

```
public void apply(Project project) {
    project.getPlugins().apply(GroovyBasePlugin.class);
    project.getPlugins().apply(JavaPlugin.class);
       project.getConfigurations().getByName(COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME).extendsFrom(
            project.getConfigurations().getByName(GroovyBasePlugin.GROOVY_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
    );
    configureGroovydoc(project);
}
```

Comment: Our plugin should not do "some stuff" when application is not present, so should not depend on it.

Comment: So add a condition that checks if `application` plugin is applied.

Comment: As you can see in the code sample, there is that check already. Problem is that application plugin does not exist in project.plugins when our plugin is being applied.