# How to make optional dependencies mandatory, or visible, with Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a Gradle plugin that needs to install JARs into a local repository before compiling a program (and other things).

To do this, I traverse the dependency tree, installing the leaves of the tree first (dependencies which don't require any other dependencies), so that when a dependency is installed which requires something, that something is already installed and things work.

The problem is that there seems to be no way to get Gradle to **show** the optional dependencies... if there is a way, then this alone would solve my problem... but supposing there isn't (reading the Gradle code I didn't see anything indicating that could be possible), then I can live with **manually adding the dependency in the build file**... however, **that won't usually work** because that causes a *broken* dependency tree where one of the branches is missing, so my code will try to install a dependency before having that optional dependency installed in the local repo (because Gradle doesn't know and doesn't tell me there's a link there!).

So we're back at square one...

So I really seem to need to be able to see optional dependencies in the dependency graph. Is there any way to achieve that?

EDIT: this is about resolving optional dependencies, which is done by Gradle, it has absolutely nothing to do with order of plugin application, as some SO editor suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enforce gradle plugins applying order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731869/how-to-enforce-gradle-plugins-applying-order)

Comment: I am not sure why you would think this question and the one you link to have anything to do with each other. Can you elaborate?

Comment: `my code will try to install a dependency before having that optional dependency installed` vs `when application plugin is included in build.gradle after our plugin`

Comment: The two things are completely unrelated. See the EDIT I made earlier. Please understand that this is not about plugin order, if you know Gradle, you should see how absurd this claim is.